# Is there a way to get a nullable value from a MongoDB C# driver projection with expression and dictionary?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

Lets say I have these classes:

```cs
public class Foo
{
   public IReadonlyDictionary<string, DateTime> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
   public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I do this projection:

```
var projection = Builders<Bar>.Projection.Expression(x => x.Foo.Values["key"])
```

I will get `DateTime.MinValue` and not a null in case the element `key` does not exist in the dictionary. The value itself indeed cannot be null (and I assume that is why MongoDB is doing `default(DateTime)`), but it can happen that it does not exist in the dictionary.

I am wondering if there is a good way to tell MongoDB that the result should be `DateTime?` so that I can get a null in case the element does not exist.

P.S. I can make the dictionary value `DateTime?`, and that will work but I would rather avoid it, since the `Value` itself should not ever be null.

Sample documents:

```json
// With values
{
  "_t": "Bar",
  "Foo":
    {
      "1521": "2022-09-26T08:25:38.502+00:00"
    }
}

// Empty
{
  "_t": "Bar",
  "Foo":
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add sample documents with and without the value?

Comment: It is still more complicated because it is in fact a dictionary of dictionaries and Bar is an implementation of an abstract class, but it is hopefully not important for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns the values as `DateTime?`; if there is no `Foo`, it is null, if it is set, it returns the value:

```
var bars = await (await barColl.FindAsync(
  Builders<Bar>.Filter.Empty, 
  new FindOptions<Bar, DateTime?>()
  {
    Projection = Builders<Bar>.Projection.Expression(
      x => (DateTime?) (x.Foo == null ? null : x.Foo.Value))
  })).ToListAsync();
```

For the following documents

```
{ "_id": { "$oid": "632dc047e08f08bfaeabc2d6" }, "Foo": null}
{ "_id": { "$oid": "632dc047e08f08bfaeabc2d7" }, "Foo": { "Value": { "$date": {  "$numberLong": "1663942727428" } } }}
```

the result is

```
null
2022-09-23T14:18:47Z
```

---

### Update: Dictionary

If you want to project the `DateTime` from a `Dictionary<string, DateTime>`, you can use the following expression with a ternary operator that checks against `default(DateTime)`:

```
var projection = Builders<SoNullableDt>.Projection
  .Expression<DateTime?>(
    x => x.Foo["1521"] == default(DateTime) ? null : x.Foo["1521"]);
var result = await (await coll.FindAsync(Builders<SoNullableDt>.Filter.Empty, 
  new FindOptions<SoNullableDt, DateTime?>() { Projection = p })).ToListAsync();
```

Based upon the sample documents (with the datetime changed to a Date data type in MongoDB), this finds the following data:

```
26.09.2022 08:25:38
null
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems I have oversimplified the example to make it easier. Your solution did not work out for me because of that. The problem is that Foo is actually never null itself, it is a dictionary where a value may not exist and complex dictionary operations do not seem to be supported, I will the update the description accordingly. Can this be overcome somehow as well?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I've updated the answer to reflect the dictionary

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, won't `x.Foo["1521"] == default(DateTime) ?` just fail when the element does not exist in a dictionary though? 

What I did now is that I made exactly the same check afterwards. I would get either a "proper" `DateTime` or `DateTime.MinValue`, and then I return null if needed.

Your solution does quite the same just inside the query.

One more thing I have noticed as well, that the generated query can be either precise (i.e. for 1521) or it can load the whole dictionary, and I suspect it will do that with your query and will be less efficient